# Array.join("\n") not the way to join with a newline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array..

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

and I want a string containing all the elements separated by a newline..

```
1

2

3

4
```

but when I try `[1,2,3,4].join("\n")` I get

```
1\n2\n3\n4
```

I feel like there is an obvious answer but I can't find it!

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Yes, but if you print that string out it will have newlines in it:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = (1..4).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
irb(main):002:0> a.join("\n")
=> "1\n2\n3\n4"
irb(main):003:0> puts a.join("\n")
1
2
3
4
```

So it does appear to achieve what you desire (?)

Answer (score 73):

A subtle error that can occur here is to use single quotes instead of double. That also has the effect of rendering the newlines as \n. So

```
puts a.join("\n")   # correct
```

is not the same as

```
puts a.join('\n')   # incorrect
```

There is an excellent write up on why this is the case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395288/double-vs-single-quotes#answer-35543086).

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a link to the explanation of why this works.

Answer (score 18):

Just in case anyone searching for this functionality in ERB template then try this :

```
(1..5).to_a.join("<br>").html_safe
```

Comment: I  prefer  `(1..5).to_a.join("\n")` , and in erb you need add style `white-space: pre-wrap`

Answer (score 6):

Try this also:

```
puts (1..4).to_a * "\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

You may not want to use html_safe, like ajay said, depending on context.  Html safe can be a security issue. This depends on if the original input was *actually* html safe.  HTML safe should not be called on input direct from a user and typically should be called before the view.

https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2013/12/19/you-never-want-to-call-html_safe-in-a-rails-template/

[edited in response to comment below]

Comment: Not necessarily. As the last line in the blog post says, **Code should never call html_safe on a string unless that code constructed the string and actually ensured it’s html-safety!**. Using `html_safe` *can* be ok, as long as you understand what it does and understand that there are security implications. Answers like this are unhelpful.

Comment: I see now, just by coincidence, that you've edited the answer - that's great, and I agree with your new working. Just a note, if you reply to the comment, I can change my vote.

Comment: However, as you now have your 50 rep, note that in future this would be more appropriate as a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As some of the other answers above imply, Rails may be escaping your code before rendering as html.  Here's a sample that addresses this problem (first sanitizing the inputs, so that you can "safely" call `html_safe` on the result):

```
my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
my_array.map{ |i| i.to_s.sanitize }.join("\n").html_safe
```

You only need `sanitize` if you don't trust the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

How about this If you wanted to print each element on new line..

```
> a = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
> a.each{|e| puts e}
1
2
3
4
 => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```