# execute curl command in ruby code

Tags: jruby, neo4j, jrubyonrails

i am trying to run following `curl` command from my ruby code

```
Kernel.system'curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" -d "{\"project\":{\"name\":\"BB\",\"description\":\"Book\"}}" "http://localhost:3000/company/projects?auth_token=mRFWyxfdPKHsDb4HhyLP"'
```

I want to do something like

`name = "BB"`(using a variable)

and then executing

`Kernel.system'curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" -d "{\"project\":{\"name\":"#{name}",\"description\":\"Book\"}}" "http://localhost:3000/company/projects?auth_token=mRFWyxfdPKHsDb4HhyLP"'`

but this approach is not working...its taking `#{name}` as string.

Please help me with this.Let me know if i am doing something wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in order to enable string interpolation you will need to use double quotes in your string. The topic has been covered here: [Double vs single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395288/ruby-double-vs-single-quotes)

also it would make your code better to read if you refactored it and assigned the parts to variables before joining them together into one string.

so:

```
host_name = 'stackoverflow.com'

Kernel.system 'curl -I #{host_name}'
```

will not work
whereas

```
Kernel.system "curl -I #{host_name}"
```

will