# Ruby Pony Gem, how to have newline in body of email

Tags: ruby, email, pony

I am using the ruby pony gem to send an automated email in my program. The problem is I cannot figure out how to give it a newline.

For example I give it,

```
    :body => 'first line\nsecond line'
```

and that is what I get in the email is:

```
    first line\nsecond line
```

instead of

```
    first line
    second line
```

How can I fix this.

Comment: try using double quotes instead of single

Comment: Can you please choose an answer if your problem is resolved ?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `:body => "first line\nsecond line"`

Single quotes (`''`) and double quotes (`""`) don't have the same meaning in ruby. Special characters (like \n or \t) are not interpreted with single quoted string.

Also you can't use string interpolation with them :

```
name = "John"
puts "My name is: #{name}" # output: "My name is John"
puts 'My name is: #{name}' # output: "My name is \#{name}"
```

You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16601500/709884).

Answer (score 0):

The body of the email will probably take and send HTML tags. Have you tried inlining html? IE:

```
:body => "First Line <br /> Second Line"
```

will result in

```
First Line
Second Line
```

Comment: Nope that doesnt work just shows: First Line <br /> Second Line   in the email

Comment: Try specifying `:headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'text/html' }` inside your `Pony.mail()` call.