# How can I have both text and a variable in link_to text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to have something like this as output:

`<a href="...">See Los Angeles</a>` or

`<a href="...">See New York</a>` etc, so New York and Los Angeles would be a variable.

How can I achieve that with Rails? I read something and tried this, but it didn't work:

```
<%= link_to 'See #{@city.name}', @city  %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, the above solution works but I had to put double quotes, not single. So this is the solution:

```
<%= link_to "See #{@city.name}", @city  %>
```

Comment: That's because ruby does not parse variables inside single quotes, only inside double quotes. It's called string interpolation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395288/ruby-double-vs-single-quotes