# Double " " or single ' ' quotation marks in Ruby - which is more correct/common?

Tags: ruby

When used to enclose strings, I'm wondering if one is more correct or common than the other? Do any firms or coding teams insist on one way or another?

Edit:

Since you would use double quotes if you are doing string interpolation, and double quotes also works for variable assigning, eg

```
str = "string"
```

Then is it acceptable to only use " " at all times? Then that saves the programmer from having to differentiate between whether to use ' ' or " ".

Comment: Sounds like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395288/ruby-double-vs-single-quotes

Answer (score 2):

The difference between " " and ' ' is that ' ' will write exactly what you are typing and with " " you can interpolate and use escaping characters like \n new line

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes if you are doing string interpolation:

```
aux = 'World'
"Hello #{aux}"
```

Use single quote otherwise

You can see [Ruby Styleguide in GitHub](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby)