# Not outputting #{variable} within a string

Tags: ruby

I cannot print an input variable as part of a string.

```
name = gets
>>> Lizzie
print #{name}
>>> Lizzie
```

That works. However, when I want to do:

```
name = gets    
print 'Your name is: #{name}'
```

it outputs:

```
Your name is: #{name}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `"` instead of `'` to quote your string.

Comment: Actually, [Ruby: double vs single quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395288/ruby-double-vs-single-quotes) has clearer answers.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski It's not a duplicate because the author most likely didn't know there was a difference between single and double quotes in Ruby. But in the end, yes it's the direction he should be pointed to.

Comment: Oh, okay, never heard of single and double quotes (guess I am such a noob :) ). Thank you for the point out!

Comment: @CyrilDD "Duplicate" doesn't mean "exactly the same question", it means "there's already a suitable answer to your question over here, have a look!"  And it causes future visitors to be directed to the most complete questions and answers.

Comment: So I checked out the answer suggested, and the problem was I should have used double quote instead of single. Guess Ruby is a bit more sensitive than Python!

Comment: The concept of single quote vs double quote interpolation comes from perl, at least.   that might make a good SO question - which languages support it?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Oh ok then you're absolutely right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why @peter_huene didn't post this as an answer, but just to complete this question the answer is:

```
name = gets    
print "Your name is: #{name}"
```

You use double quotes to get variable injection and other features. Single quotes are literal quotes with no post processing.

@Lizzie - Ruby isn't "more sensitive" - it offers you two explicit ways of handling strings, which is more flexible. Unfortunately this means a bit of "magic" in that strings behave differently depending on how quoted, but it's a feature not a peculiarity.