# Why does respond_to? need symbols as arguments in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arguments, symbols

Why does this method only accept symbols and not strings as its arguments?

```
x = 10
x.respond_to?(next)
```

Pushing a string like the above would throw `(ruby):1: void value expression`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does accept strings:

```
x = 10
x.respond_to?('next')
# => true
```

Your problem is that you didn't pass string, but `next` keyword.

Comment: So, it's interchangeable?

Comment: `'next'` string and `:next` symbol? Yes, in this context.

Comment: Another side question, are single quotes are interchangeable with double quotes? In Java, they're only used with char.

Comment: @therewillbecoffee http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395288/double-vs-single-quotes

Answer (score 1):

From Ruby [respond_to?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) doc:

```
respond_to?(symbol, include_all=false) → true or false 
respond_to?(string, include_all=false) → true or false
```

It accepts both, symbol and string. And if string passed it is converted to a symbol.

As mentioned by Marek, you didn't pass string, neither symbol and have a syntax error with built-in keyword.