# what is the difference between single quote ( ' ) and double quote ( " ) in cocoapod?

Tags: ruby, cocoapods

As i am very familiar with `Cocoapod` library to integrate 3rd party `iOS` library in our project with very easy steps and versioning also in managed way and very easy to upgrade version of any 3rd party library.

Generally we are using below `command` for any 3rd party library in `POD` file to get in our project.

```
POD '<Library Name>'
```

One more we are using was

```
POD "<Library Name>"
```

so may i know what is the logical difference between both of this command ?

Comment: i think this must be in a syntax to include cocoa pods to any project ..or [have a look](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16601500/4003548)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes are used for just strings.

Where as Double quotes are used for both strings and string interpolation.

**Example**:

```
name = 'User Name' //User Name

welcome_note_using_sigle_qoute = 'Welcome #{name}' //Welcome /#{name}
welcome_note_using_double_qoute = "Welcome #{name}"  //Welcome User Name
```

Comment: what i understand by your clarification that its accept space if we put "" and ' not accept any space in string right ?

Comment: no. check my answer once i have updated. Single quotes are just used to specify/define strings. But Double Quotes you can use to specify/define strings and string interpolation.

Comment: yes, you are right but in iOS we are not using any string interpolation in `cococapod` so in that case both are same ?

Comment: Check it once, in ruby we use to use for string interpolation. Since **CocoaPods** are written in **Ruby** i think it will work.

Comment: Ok Thank for your detail description on this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a podfile is essentially a Ruby source code file, therefore what applies is the difference between `'` and `"` and Ruby:

[Double vs single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395288/double-vs-single-quotes)

(single quotes make the string to be interpreted literally, without string interpolation and ignoring character escaping).

Taking an example from [CocoaPods Podfile Documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html):

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
     puts "#{target.name}"
  end
end
```

The string interpolation `#{...}` wouldn't be possible with single quotes.

The question what you should use is probably subjective and depends on the usage.