# #{} is not working on ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, css

I've been trying to show random images everytime a user post something. 
I have images name "kejang (#).png" # ranging from 1 to 21.

So I have done this.

```
<div class = 'article_header'>
    <div class = 'article_img'>
        <% kj_num = rand(20) + 1 %>
        <%= kj_num %>
        <%= image_tag 'kejang (#{kj_num}).PNG' %>
    </div>
```

It does run on the server but returns no image, only 'x' marked crashed images.

I wondered where it went wrong and altered #{kj_num} with regular number and it worked. (i.e, I put 2 or 3 instead of #{kj_num} and it worked.)

Why is #{kj_num} not working ?? 
Rails interpretting #{variable} as a simple text. How should I change my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[#{} vs. single vs. double quotes](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/60278)**

Here you need to use double quotes `(")` rather than single quotes `(')`

```
<div class = 'article_header'>
    <div class = 'article_img'>
        <% kj_num = rand(20) + 1 %>
        <%= kj_num %>
        <%= image_tag "kejang (#{kj_num}).PNG" %>
    </div>
</div>
```

String interpolation is the process of converting placeholders inside a string to the values they represent, in order to produce a dynamic string. You probably use it all the time without realizing just how cool it works under the hood, and how you can leverage this power in your own classes.

```
person = 'World'
puts "Hello, #{person}!"
```

https://kconrails.com/2010/12/08/ruby-string-interpolation/

Comment: Thank you so much for the super fast answer. I was really stuck and I was frustrated and I desperately came to Stackoverflow. The answer was posted soooo fast and it just solved my problem in a second. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use string interpolation inside single quotes which will not work. You have to use double quotes instead

Here is an example to understand it,

```
jruby-1.7.13 :001 > name  = 'ajinkya'
=> "ajinkya"
jruby-1.7.13 :002 > 'hello, #{name}'
=> "hello, \#{name}"
jruby-1.7.13 :003 > "hello, #{name}"
=> "hello, ajinkya"
```

More detailed explanation about [Double vs single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395288/double-vs-single-quotes)

Comment: Thank you so much. I never thought double and single quotes were different! Amazing new knowledge