# Colorise part of string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, colors, console

I am new to Ruby and I want a part of a string to be colored. For this, I wrote a class Painter

```
class Painter
  Red='\033[0;31m'          # Red color
  Green='\033[0;32m'        # Green color
.
.
.
  def paint(text, color)
    return "#{color}#{text}\e[0m"
  end
end
```

The way I use this is

```
puts "Green color looks like #{Painter.new.paint("this", Painter::Green)} and Red color looks like #{Painter.new.paint("this", Painter::Red)}"
```

I expect the output to look like this -
[image: expected output]

But the output on the console looks like -
[image: problematic output]

I can solve the problem if I write methods like

```
def greenify(text)
  return "\033[0;32m#{text}\e[0m"
end
```

But this means too many methods for one cause. Is there a way I can generify this?

Comment: it's because you use single quotes for the colors. Escape sequences like `\033`  are not handled in single quotes but are in double quotes https://stackoverflow.com/a/16601500/3072566

Comment: Ohh thanks, you can add this as an answer so that it'll help others. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you use single quotes for the colors. Escape sequences like `\033` are not handled in single quotes but are in double quotes.

[Source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16601500/3072566)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an existing solution for this, I recommend you take a look at the gem [Colorize](https://github.com/fazibear/colorize). You can not only colorize your string, but make them bold too. Example:

```
require 'colorize'

puts 'this is a blue string'.blue
puts "this is part #{'blue'.blue} and part #{'red'.red}"
puts "this is part #{'blue'.blue}, part #{'red'.red} and bold".bold
```