# how to show properly using Rspec the Double Quote Mark's " "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, html-safe

I'm using Rspec and the gem file_validators for testing and I need to put properly the output of the Quote Marks ("txt") like theses:

```
expect(page).to have_content expect(page).to have_content "You are not allowed to upload \"txt\" files, allowed types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png"
```

or

```
double_quotes = "&quot;txt&quot;".html_safe
expect(page).to have_content expect(page).to have_content "You are not allowed to upload #{double_quotes} files, allowed types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png"
```

But I'm having a failure error for show this:

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content   expect(page).to have_content "You are not allowed to upload #{double_quotes} files, allowed types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png"
   expected to find text "You are not allowed to upload &quot;txt&quot; files, allowed types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png" in "News CityToggle navigationHomeAdminSigned in as rubie@fayvon.netSign out×Post has not been created.New Post* TitleSubtitleFileYou are not allowed to upload \"txt\" files, allowed types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png* Content It will serve for show images about the posts."
```

Someone can help me with this problem?
The entire output needs to be like these:

```
You are not allowed to upload "rtf" files, allowed types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quote the string:

```
expect(page).to have_content('You are not allowed to upload "txt" files, allowed types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png')
```

There are [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395288/double-vs-single-quotes) that better explain the details of single quotes vs double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I put this and work's:

```
str = "You are not allowed to upload \"txt\" files, allowed types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png"
expect(page).to have_content "#{str}"
```

thank's @anothermh

Comment: You don't need `"#{str}"`. Use this instead: `expect(page).to have_content(str)`

Comment: Why would you not have just accepted the answer given rather than essentially repeating it and then giving credit

Comment: Not everyone knows [what to do when someone answers a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) but hopefully @rld will read it for their next question.

Comment: The thing was I was trying to do the code to pass, and when I get it I saw the answer of the anothermh. Nothing about the help of him but I like more the mine and I want to do quickly because of the hour and I just put here for for share, it's a one more answer for help others. Anyway thank's for show me this I will read.

Comment: I'm sorry guys I was in the library and because of the time(the library closing) I don't vote up on the answer of the anothermh, I forget. And I was trying to pass the code and so when I get to pass I post my answer, for share. And yes, I'm never readed that before. Anyway thank you for the help.