# How to apply an aviglitch script to every file in a folder?

Tags: ruby, video, data-moshing

I'm struggling to use an aviglitch script on every file in a folder.
I would need it to
1. open every file and perform the alterations
2. export every new file with an prepended glitch_ in front of the original filename

Here are the relevant lines of code:

```
Dir.glob("*.avi") do |filename|

a = AviGlitch.open '#{filename}'

o.output 'glitch_#{filename}'

end
```

The script gives me following error:

"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Projects\VIDEO\0000_BLENDER SCRIPT RENDER\cig_fast_2frames\8frames>cig_fast_2frames_glitch.rb
Traceback (most recent call last):
        7: from C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Projects/VIDEO/0000_BLENDER SCRIPT RENDER/cig_fast_2frames/8frames/cig_fast_2frames_glitch.rb:6:in `<main>'
        6: from C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Projects/VIDEO/0000_BLENDER SCRIPT RENDER/cig_fast_2frames/8frames/cig_fast_2frames_glitch.rb:6:in`glob'
        5: from C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Projects/VIDEO/0000_BLENDER SCRIPT RENDER/cig_fast_2frames/8frames/cig_fast_2frames_glitch.rb:8:in `block in <main>'
        4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/aviglitch-0.1.5/lib/aviglitch.rb:46:in`open'
        3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/aviglitch-0.1.5/lib/aviglitch.rb:46:in `new'
        2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/aviglitch-0.1.5/lib/aviglitch/base.rb:18:in`initialize'
        1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/aviglitch-0.1.5/lib/aviglitch/base.rb:18:in `open'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/aviglitch-0.1.5/lib/aviglitch/base.rb:18:in`initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - #{filename} (Errno::ENOENT)"

If I run the script with manually typed in filenames it works. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the whole code:

```
require 'aviglitch'

Dir.glob("*.avi") do |filename|

a = AviGlitch.open '#{filename}'       # Rewrite this line for your file.
rep = 3
inc_rep = 0
inc_fr = 1
framecount = 0
d = []
a.frames.each_with_index do |f, i|
  d.push(i) if f.is_deltaframe?     # Collecting non-keyframes indices.
end
q = a.frames[0, 5]                  # Keep first key frame.

6.times do
  x = a.frames[d[framecount], 1]  # Select a certain non-keyframe.
  q.concat(x * rep)            # Repeat the frame n times and concatenate with q.
framecount = framecount + inc_fr
rep = rep + inc_rep
end
o = AviGlitch.open q                # New AviGlitch instance using the frames.
o.mutate_keyframes_into_deltaframes!(range = nil)
o.output 'glitch_#{filename}'

end
```

Thank you

Benni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do string interpolation inside single-quote strings (`'`), which does not work as these do not allow string interpolation or escape sequences (such as `\n`).

Use double-quote strings (`"`) instead:

```
Dir.glob("*.avi") do |filename|
  a = AviGlitch.open(filename)  # no string interpolation needed here, just passing the filename is enough
  o.output "glitch_#{filename}"
end
```

See also [Double vs single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395288/double-vs-single-quotes)